# JQuery Date Range Picker Giving Uncaught TypeError. Any ideas on where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added a JQuery daterangepicker to my page but it's not working.

I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

As far as I can see everything has been added correctly.

Here's the code I've added to my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />
```

And I added this to the footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="#tmp_input-29453 > input"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });

  $('input[name="#tmp_input-29453 > input"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="#tmp_input-29453 > input"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
</script>
```

The CSS ID for the input field is: #tmp_input-29453

I'm not sure what I've done wrong but here is the link to the page:
[Rental Page](https://app.funnel-preview.com/for_domain/www.minutecarrentals.com/sales-page-449136581606702579168?updated_at=a10b5200b05229bd9850472a24404c45v2&track=0&preview=true)

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong??

Comment: I am betting you have more than one version of jquery on your page.

Comment: I tried deleting each line one by one and same issue... Thanks though... @epascarello

Comment: You have two versions of jQuery on your page. Just looked.